# Ajuda com Visual G

Tags: visualg

Estou com um problema no Visual G. É um exercício da faculdade (ADS - 1º Semestre).

Preciso criar um identificador de número par ou ímpar, porém, sem usar `MOD`, divisão ou multiplicação, apenas soma e subtração e só com os comandos `Escreva`/`Escreval`, `leia`, `se`, `entao` e `senao`. Já tentei de diversas formas mas até agora não deu certo.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Segue meu código:

```
Var

 num:inteiro

 Inicio

  escreva("Olá usuário, digite um número: ")
    leia (num)

  se num +2 = 2,4,6,8,0 entao 
  escreva("Este número é par!")

  senao
  escreva("Este número é impar!") 

   fimse  
Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Olá @Azerus, bem vindo ao **SOpt**. Coloque pf o código que já tem, e que já experimentou, para o podermos ajudar melhor.

Comment: *"porém, sem usar MOD, Divisão ou Multiplicação"* bem difícil sem usar isso, acho que você primeiro precisa resolver o problema da matemática antes de pensar no algorítimo, porque, segundo o site [brasilescola.uol.com.br](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/o-que-e/matematica/o-que-sao-numeros-pares-impares.htm): *"Os pares são aqueles terminados em 0, 2, 4, 6 ou 8. Já os ímpares são aqueles que não são pares e são terminados em 1, 3, 5, 7 ou 9."*, diferente do que todos constuma pensar que, número par é aquele que divido por 2 não traz resto, o que é uma verdade, mas...

Comment: olhando por essa outra definição, você precisa pegar o número o ver seu último dígito, pense nisso...

Comment: @JoãoMartins Este é o código que estou usando: Var

 num:inteiro

Inicio

      escreva("Olá usuário, digite um número: ")
         leia (num)

      se num +2 = 2,4,6,8,0 entao
         escreva("Este número é par!")
      
      senao
         escreva("Este número é impar!")

      fimse
      
Fimalgoritmo

Comment: @Azerus clique no botão `editar` para editar sua pergunta e insira o código nela fornecendo mais detalhes do problema.

Comment: @gato claro, pronto!

Comment: @Azerus você quer criar um algoritmo que identifique o numero par ou ímpar sem usar uma formula matemática?

Comment: @gato exato, apenas com soma e subtração.

Comment: @Azerus então você esta a usar a matemática, se pretende usar soma ou subtração.

Comment: @gato sim, apenas soma e subtração...